# Mongoose update subdocument by key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

for the following collection:

```
id: Number
name:[ 
       new Schema({
           language: { type: String, enum: ['en-US', 'fr-CA'] },
           text: String,
       },{ _id: false }
       );
     ],
isActive: Boolean
```

and sample data like the following:

```
{
  id:1,
  "name": [
            {"language": "en-US", "text": "Book"},
            {"language": "fr-CA", "text": "livre"}
          ],
   isActive:true
   // and so many other fields
},
{
  id:2,
  "name": [
            {"language": "en-US", "text": "Pen"}
          ],
   isActive:true
   // and so many other fields
}
```

I would like to update the document by Id:1 and change the text only for french, I tried by:

```
const input={ "id":"1", "isActive": false}
const name= { "name": [{"language": "fr-CA", "text": "Nouvel article"}]}
await langs.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: input.id },
    { ...input, $addToSet: { name } },
    { new: true, upsert: true }
  );
```

but the result is: (added another french item)

```
{
  id:1,
  "name": [
            {"language": "en-US", "text": "Book"},
            {"language": "fr-CA", "text": "livre"},
            {"language": "fr-CA", "text": "Nouvel article"}
          ],
   isActive:false
},
```

This is based on Brit comment:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/atlw5ZKoYiI

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

As long as that attribute already exists on the document, you can do something like:

```
   Collection.findOneAndUpdate({id: 1}, {
        $set: {
          "name.$[elem]": name
        }
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [  { "elem.language":  name.language  } ],
        upsert: true,
        new: true
      })
```

Comment: Thanks @Brit, I have used the following code as you advise, it is changing it but it is not adding if it does not exist (upsert:true) 

  const payItem = await langs.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: input.id },
    { $set: { 'name.$[elem]': name, ...input } },
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.language': name.language }],
      upsert: true,
      new: true,
    }
  );

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/atlw5ZKoYiI